# Qt 5.6 - QPushButton clicked connect issue

Tags: c++, qt

Sorry for my English,
I just started to use Qt and C++, I want to try call slots from different class when I clicked the button. So far it didnt work well.
if I called slot method like this, it's work like a charm

```
connect(ui.pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onPushButtonClicked);

void MainWindow::onPushButtonClicked() {
    testClassObject->SomeMethod();
    qDebug() << "Button clicked!";
}
```

but it wont work like this and I dont know why and couldnt figure it out.

```
connect(ui.pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, testClassObject, &TestClass::SomeMethod);
```

*TestClass in here is not null, correct object
*connect I check and it return true

If someone could explain my mistake or why this is not working would be great.

Comment: Sorry but we cannot accept questions that don't provide self-contained code or that link/suggest external resources (especially if they are repositories, since their contents may change and make the question completely invalid). Please take your time to [edit] your question and provide a proper [mre].

Comment: Is `TestClass::SomeMethod` in the `public slots:` section of the TestClass declaration?  If it's just a normal C++ method (i.e. not declared as a slot) then I wouldn't expect it to work as a slot.

Comment: I tried both, now in the slots and still it is not working, but try different approach and I dont know it is same thing but
`bool pushButtonIsPressed = false;` 
`connect(ui.pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]() {` 
`pushButtonIsPressed = !pushButtonIsPressed;`
`testClassObject->SomeMethod(pushButtonIsPressed);` 
`qDebug() << "Toggling:" << pushButtonIsPressed; });`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried to add an argument to like this:

`MainWindow::onPushButtonClicked(bool checked)`

Comment: I didnt but do I need that? onPushButtonClicked method work fine, I dont want to use onPushButtonClicked() method, I want to directly connect SomeMethod() from TestClass like the second code line. I might misunderstood you, if I am could you give me more detail.

Comment: ok I was dealing and now I understand what did you tried to say me I did like this and it is worked.
```bool pushButtonIsPressed = false;
connect(ui.pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]() {
  pushButtonIsPressed = !pushButtonIsPressed; // Toggle the state
  testClassObject->SomeMethod(pushButtonIsPressed);
  qDebug() << "Toggling:" << pushButtonIsPressed;
 });
```